# Schiller Stock Data

Tags: stocks, historical-data, market-data, cpi

I was analysing the data provided by Schiller (http://www.econ.yale.edu/~shiller/data.htm). On the first row (year 1871) the value for CPI index is 12.46. Anyone know the source of this value? I thought it was the accumulated CPI index, but i couldn't get this value.[Schiller dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnUOL.png)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the [link](http://www.econ.yale.edu/~shiller/data.htm) you posted... (emphasis mine)

> The CPI-U (Consumer Price Index-All Urban Consumers) published by the U.S. Bureau of Labor Statistics begins in 1913; **for years before 1913 1 spliced to the CPI Warren and Pearson's price index, by multiplying it by the ratio of the indexes in January 1913.** December 1999 and January 2000 values for the CPI-Uare extrapolated. See George F. Warren and Frank A. Pearson, Gold and Prices (New York: John Wiley and Sons, 1935). Data are from their Table 1, pp. 11–14.